# Replace list components based on index location

Tags: python, list

I want to replace list components based on their location pls i.e. replace paul and wayne with bill.  How can i do this?

```
>>> names = ['ben','paul','susan','gary']
>>> names[3] = 'wayne'
>>> print(names)
['ben', 'paul', 'susan', 'wayne']

>>> names[1,3] = 'bill'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

This comes about because I am trying to create a word game.  So for example

Given a list which contains:
['f','l','e','e']
And another masked word list which contains ['*','*','*','*']

How can i replace the characters in position 2 and 3 in my masked word list if my game player guesses the letter 'e'?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `names[1], names[3] = "bill", "bill"`? What's the actual logic for the change?

Comment: OK - for a word game i am identifying the location of the character or guess entered (including if it occurs more than once).  That location is given to me in a list.  I would like to change the 'masked' copy of the word to use the locations given to me to show the guess. i.e. ----- becomes --nn- for benny.

Given how many times i do not know a letter could be in a word, i was hoping to just use the list of locations and have that replace the locations of - with my last guess.

Comment: That is completely not what is implied from your question. Try to [edit] it to be more clear and have a [mre]. You can use the help of [ask]

Comment: You should visualize what you written down in that comment in your actual question. Sample input, sample output. Your current question doesn't seem te reflect what you are actually imply to achieve.

Comment: Now try to reflect that problem in the code you provided. The code in the question right now doesn't really portray the problem. For example, given an index from one list - change the element in that index of the other list.

Comment: Thanks anyway -  Kashyap kn  pointed me in the direction i'm trying to go in.  Probably not the best way to do a word game, but i'm learning :)

Comment: You can look around in stack overflow, I got to see many questions regarding this kind of "hangman" game. You might get some inspiration. Good luck! You can use this search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hangman+%5Bpython%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we know the indexes to be updated we can do something like this

```
names = ['ben','paul','susan','gary']
value = 'bill'
indexes = [1,3,..]

for index in indexes:
    names[index] = value
```

Comment: Thanks so much - annoyingly simple.  Thats great!